# Compare a string and an array, but leave out words not surrounded by whitespaces

Tags: javascript, html

I want to compare a string and and array in order to get words or phrases in the string that are present in the array; but I do not want to include words from the string that are not surrounded by whitespaces.

The below code compares userInput and myArray and produced this result: morning,good,good morning,go,he.
You would see that "go" and "he" are also included, although they are not separate words in userInput ("go" is from "good" and "he" is from "hello"). I researched on regular expression but couldn't figure out how to use them. I need help on how to exclude "go" and "he" from the result.

```
const userInput = "hello good morning everyone";
const myArray = ["tomorrow", "morning", "good", "good morning", "go", "he"];
const intersect = myArray.filter(word => 
userInput.includes(word)  
);
  
document.write(intersect);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can instantiate a new `RegExp` for each `phrase` in `myArray` and execute it on the `userInput`.

- Make sure wrap the phrase in word-boundaries (`\b`)
- You could also add a case-ignore flag (`i`) to ignore case sensitivity

```js
const
  userInput = "hello good morning everyone",
  myArray   = ["tomorrow", "morning", "good", "good morning", "go", "he"],
  intersect = myArray.filter(phrase =>
                new RegExp(`\\b${phrase}\\b`, 'i').exec(userInput));
  
console.log(intersect); // [ "morning", "good", "good morning" ]
```

Here is a an example with with live input evaluation and a debounce:

```js
const
  inputEl = document.querySelector('#input'),
  phrases = ['tomorrow', 'morning', 'good', 'good morning', 'go', 'he'];

const getIntersections = (input, phrases) =>
  phrases.filter(phrase =>
    new RegExp(`\\b${phrase}\\b`, 'i').exec(input));

const handleInput = ({ target: { value } }) => {
  const intersections = getIntersections(value, phrases);
  console.log(intersections);
};

inputEl.addEventListener('input', debounce(handleInput, 250));
inputEl.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('input'));

// Source: https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function
function debounce(func, wait, immediate) {
  let timeout;
  return function() {
    const context = this, args = arguments, later = function() {
      timeout = null;
      if (!immediate) func.apply(context, args);
    };
    const callNow = immediate && !timeout;
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);
    if (callNow) func.apply(context, args);
  };
};
```

```html
<input id="input" type="text" value="hello good morning everyone" />
```

Comment: Hi Mr. Polywhirl, the i flag came in handy, and your solution did work, like the other solution, except for the fact that the regex resulted in latency in typing text in the userInput field; how can one solve this problem?

Comment: @DieudonneTambah what user input field?

Comment: UserInput field is the text box where a user types in the text that will be compared with myArray

Comment: I'll just post it as a full question, so that you can get the full picture.

Answer (score 1):

Regex is very powerful, and I highly recommend you become familiar with it. Using a site like regexr.com will help, because you can test things there instantly.

The `\b` part is a word boundary (with two `\`'s because they need to be escaped)

```js
const userInput = "hello good morning everyone";
const myArray = ["tomorrow", "morning", "good", "good morning", "go", "he"];
const intersect = myArray.filter(word => userInput.match(new RegExp("\\b" + word + "\\b")));

console.log(intersect);
```

Comment: Hello Sean Kendle, the solution you provided works, except that the RegExp results in latency when inputting text in the userInput field of my app (there is delay with each letter I type); is there a way to mitigate this?

Comment: You should post this as a full question with working code in a snippet and link to it below, and I and others can help you with that. In short, rather than using onInput, you can use onChange or, use onInput, but implement a setTimeout that gets reset each key press, and then runs your logic some 10-50ms after input so it's not running on every single keypress.

Comment: I'll post it as a full question. Thanks.